# Type mismatch when sorting 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, type-conversion

This method is supposed to take a 2 rows by 3 columns array `m`, sort it and output the sorted array

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Foo {  
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[][] m1 = { { 14, 11, 13, 12 },
                    { 18, 15, 13, 13 },
                    { 19, 16, 15, 17 } };
     sortRows(m1);
   }
   public static int[][] sortRows(int[][] m) {
     int sorted[][] = new int[2][3];
     for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        sorted[i] = Arrays.sort( m[i] ); //ERROR- cannot convert from void to int
     }
   return sorted;
   }
}
```

I can't imagine where a void would come from. What does that even mean?

Comment: Could you show the calling code?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to read the Javadoc documentation and see what does `Arrays.sort()` actually return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `Arrays.sort()` is a `void` method and it doesn't have return value

When in doubt, check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[]))

Comment: Yes. [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-)

Comment: So Arrays.sort() changes the original array? Then I think I have to duplicate the array before sorting it..

Comment: @Jack Yes exactly. calling `Arrays.sort( m[i] )` will sort your array `m`